# Blender weight issue to Unity

Tags: weight-painting, unity

[image]

I have a mesh and rig, I have one bone for jiggle effect, the right one that I have moved to right, but in Unity there's a jaggy edge. Why?

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210801/weight-paint-different-from-unreal-engine/210828#210828

Comment: thank you, eventually i found out it's problem in Unity